# speed up sync files from server to remote backup storage (currently using rsync)

Tags: synchronization, rsync

Need to speed up the sync of a local folder with hundreds of thousands files (small and big) to a remote sshsfs storage. Currently using rsync but open to anything else.

Usually less than 1% of them have been modified.
The remote sshfs storage is very slow because the need of rsync  of building the filelist of the remote folder (local is fast).

Since the remote storage is used primarly as a backup and it is not going to ever change, there is any way to avoid the need of building the remote file list to let rsync compare what is new or updated?

An alternative solution would be an async tool if there it able to track changes in local folder/subfolders, but I know none.

Thanks in advance!